# Airflow Plugin with FAB: route to login page if session is expired

Tags: airflow, flask-appbuilder

I have written an Airflow plugin which extends the Airflow webserver UI. Flask Appbuilder (www_rbac) is used. When the user session is expired and the user tries to access a route in my plugin where authentication is required, he gets an error message:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'login'. Did you mean 'AuthDBView.login' instead?
```

I guess that I need to do some configuration in my plugin to tell Airflow to route to *airflow.login*, but could not find out how to do that.

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem with endpoint?

Comment: @NicolaBen no, I ignore it for the time being. :-(